# Load data to cloth simulation setting

Tags: python, cloth-simulation

I want to write a program that can write a json file that record values for cloth simulation setting and read the json file.

For example, when I finish a good cloth simulation, I can export a json file that contains all the values assigned in quality, mass, air and sprint etc.

Or when I load the json file, blender assign 3 to air_damping in ClothSettings if "air_damping":3 is read. If there is no "mass" key in the json, blender use the default mass value or the assigned value in blender.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I am silly.... `setattr(settings, "mass", 0.5)` makes it......

Comment: If settings is a blender `ClothSettings` instance could also use `settings.mass = 0.5` ... which is IMO more readable, I'd use set attribute when you have `key, value` pairs  `setattr(settings, key, value)`